# Are there any CLI-based consumers for ActiveMQ?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe

Are there any cli-based consumers for ActiveMQ 5.16.2 that I can use to check the messages being queued to a topic, or a way (GUI/CLI-based) to check the messages being published.

A simple jar can definitely be written for this, but I have a feeling that there should be something that people are already using for this.

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.16.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ActiveMQ "Classic" and ActiveMQ Artemis ship with some command-line tools you can use. The relevant commands in ActiveMQ "Classic" are:

- `consumer`
- `producer`
- `browse`

For example, you can send messages with the `producer` command, e.g.:

```
$ ./activemq producer --destination queue://myQueue
```

You can then browse those messages with the `browse` command, e.g.:

```
$ ./activemq browse myQueue
```

And you can finally consume those messages with the `consume` command, e.g.:

```
$ ./activemq consumer --destination queue://myQueue
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. `activemq consumer --destination topic://mytopic`